# ASP.NET Core StackExchange.Redis Filtering Value

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, redis, stackexchange.redis

I have a .NET Core 6.0 project that I use StackExchange.Redis.

First, I am wondering if I can filter the value coming with Key-Value pair.

When I get the key, I get all the values and after that I am filtering them.

Is there anyway to filter values before getting them all or I have to filter it after getting all the values ?

-- TestModel2.cs

```
public class TestModel2
{
  public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
  public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

-- RedisCacheService.cs

```
public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string key) where T : class
{
  string value = await _client.GetDatabase().StringGetAsync(key);
  return value.ToObject<T>();
}
```

--ToObject

```
public static T ToObject<T>(this string value) where T : class
{
  return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? null : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
}
```

--CacheController.cs

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetProductsByCategoryId")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetProductsByCategoryId(int id)
{
    var models = await _cacheService.GetAsync<List<TestModel2>>("models3");
    if (models != null && models?.Count() > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            var model = models[0].Products.Where(x => x.CategoryId == id);
            if (model != null)
            {
                return Ok(model);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return StatusCode(500);
        }
    }
    return BadRequest("Not Found");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a single `string`, then no: redis doesn't have inbuilt filtering commands (unless you use something like [`RedisJSON`](https://redis.io/docs/stack/json/) on the server, but that isn't part of core redis). Redis doesn't have rich columnar filtering like you might find in, say, a SQL database. The idea is that you create your own explicit indexing using redis primitives. Storing all the data in a single string and fetching the entire thing out each time is not optimal.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Do you recommend using RedisJSON ?  And getting all the values and filtering it would affect the performance of the project ?

Comment: I have no experience positive or negative with RedisJSON; all I can say is: "it exists". For performance: I can't comment on that without knowing, for example, how big the payload is, how often you're fetching it, and whether you're caching anything

Answer (score 0):

I also found after searching about how to filter and something like that, RediSearch also can be used and integrated with ASP.NET Core Project...

If you are using Docker, RedisLabs/redismod is useful for it...